# Rails - calling a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

My question is so simple that I am hesitating to ask. (Why are all examples provided in the documentation unnecessary complicated?)

I want to transfer the title section for my rails project in a partial (DRY...).
Very much simplified, the calling line in my `show.html.erb` is:

```
<%= render "shared/headerblock", locals: {cntrnm: @cntrlst.CountrName } %>
```

Let's reduce the code in the partial `_headerblock.html.erb` to the absolute minimum:

```
My Countryname is <%= cntrnm %>
```

Rails complains (even without the plain text containing the passed variable):

> undefined local variable or method 'cntrnm' ...

What's wrong? (BTW: also just passing a `string` instead of the `instance` variable from`@cntrlst` produces this error.)

As far as I can see, I just copied what I found in all kinds of tutorials and blogs. - - - Obviously not ;-)

Comment: Try with `render partial: 'shared/headerblock', locals: { cntrnm: @cntrlst.CountrName }`. With the explicit "partial:" option.

Answer (score 1):

rails have 2 cases It's up to you

Case 1:

```
<%= render partial "shared/headerblock", locals: {cntrnm: @cntrlst.CountrName } %>
```

Case 2:

```
<%= render "shared/headerblock", cntrnm: @cntrlst.CountrName %>
```

Comment: Case 1 works, BUT ONLY with " partial: " as suggested by arieljuod, not without the colons. Thx!