# Rails 5 yield gives duplicate contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am figuring out why it showing duplicate data on the front page:

[image]

All I did is to use Rails collection rendering.

Here's my application.html.erb file:

```
  <body>

  <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
  <!-- content -->
    <main class="pt-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
          <%= yield %>
         <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my index.html.erb file:

```
   <div class="col-md-9">
    <% if @contacts.blank? %>  
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <strong>Record is empty!</strong>
        </div>
    <% else %>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header"><strong>All Contacts</strong></div>

      <table class="table">
         <%= render @contacts %>            
      </table>    
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

and here's my _contact.html.erb file:

```
      <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
        <tr>
          <td class="middle">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">

                   <%= image_tag contact.gravatar, class: "media-object" %>

                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading"><%= contact.name %></h4>
                <address>
                  <strong><%= contact.address %>, <%= contact.city %>, <%= contact.state %>, <%= contact.zip %></strong><br>
                  <%= contact.email %> | <%= contact.phone %> | <%= contact.mobile %>
                </address>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td width="100" class="middle">
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle btn-xs" title="Edit">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-circle btn-xs" title="Delete">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

BTW, I am using Kaminari Gem for pagination. It works however the data shows twice.

Any idea?

UPDATES:

Here's my contacts controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.page params[:page]
  end
end
```

Here's the kaminari config file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.default_per_page = 2
  # config.max_per_page = 4
  # config.window = 4
  # config.outer_window = 0
  # config.left = 0
  # config.right = 0
  # config.page_method_name = :page
  # config.param_name = :page
  # config.params_on_first_page = false
end
```

Comment: All looks good, it's like `@contacts` has the duplicated data. Can you please check with a `puts "@contacts: #{@contacts.inspect}"` in your controller ?

Comment: Here's the output after putting puts "@contacts: #{@contacts.inspect}" --> https://jsfiddle.net/dm7ybgje/

Comment: try change  `<%= render @contacts %>`  to ` <%= render 'contact' %>`

Comment: @leafeve 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: change this string path to your file(_contact.html.erb). exp <%= render "users/products/contact"%>
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203466/rails-calling-a-partial/58205470#58205470)

Comment: at leafeve For some reason if I changed it to <%= render "contacts/contact" %>    it works like a charm. why then @contacts doesn't work? Do you know the reason why? explain?

Comment: leafeve: are there anyway I can still manage to work with @contacts instead the whole path?

Comment: leafeve: are there anyway I can still manage to work with @contacts instead the whole path?

Comment: yes, u can use @contacts. [read more]https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Comment: i use  `<%= render partial: "contact", object: @contacts %>`   and works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `<%= render @contacts %>`, Rails will loop results from `@contacts` and render each one using `_contact.html.erb`, while embedding local variable `contact` in each one. You see contacts twice, because you loop twice: remove `<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>` from `_contact.html.erb` and it should work.